# getResource() of ClassLoader returns null when single quote in path

Tags: java

I'm trying to get ressource of an SQL file in src/main/resources.

I have managed to get my file with this :

```
String sqlFileName = "query.sql";
URL url = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(sqlFileName);
```

But not if there's a single quote in sqlFileName like this

```
String sqlFileName = "John's query.sql";
URL url = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(sqlFileName);
```

getResource returns null since it can't find my resource when there's an apostrophe. I tried several methods to escape my single quote such as \' and '' and none of these worked.

I am expecting to get a url with getResource similar to this :

```
C:\Projects\ProjectA\src\main\resources\queries\John's query.sql
```

Comment: try escaping single quote `\'`

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the actual resource that you're expecting it to find?

Comment: Seriously, why bother with an apostrophe in sql filename. Do you really need it?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this… until I noticed I was using the wrong case for one of the letters, which is why it seemed to work without a .jar, but didn't work inside a .jar.  (Jar file entry names are always case sensitive, even in Windows.)

Comment: @Tomas Pinos Because in french, it is standard to use apostrophes in our file names (look at the amount of apostrophes in french texts). It's not realistic to tell everyone not to use apostrophes in their filenames.

Comment: What about `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(sqlFileName, "UTF-8")` ?

Comment: It works for me... I can't reproduce the bug.

Comment: Are you sure it is the quote and not the space?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try escaping it with \\' ?

With one \', you create an escaped ' for the String, but is not passed to the URL parser. You want to escape the \ itself, so that both the ' and the \ are both passed to the parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try encoding the filename,

URLEncoder.encode("french'filename.txt", "UTF-8"));

It will return: french%27filename.txt You can choose a different encoding if you need to.